# GitKraken crashing when I attempt to open preferences

Tags: arch-linux, crash, manjaro

I recently installed Manjaro. Things are working great for the most part, but GitKraken keeps crashing when I attempt to open the "Preferences" page. It'll crash, then reopen, but the preferences page won't appear.

This is the output when I run it from terminal:

```
(node:3255) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:3255) [DEP0106] DeprecationWarning: crypto.createDecipher is deprecated.
(electron) 'allowRendererProcessReuse' is deprecated and will be removed.
state:  unavailable
state:  checking
state:  unavailable
App Window: WebContents 2 render process unexpectedly missing: crashed
MessagePort is terminating
MessagePort is terminating
MessagePort is terminating
MessagePort is terminating
MessagePort is terminating
Error occurred in handler for 'LOAD_ORGANIZATION_SUMMARIES': MessagePort is terminating
[PERFORMANCE] tried to end event with no start time: opening renderer window
state:  checking
state:  unavailable
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to be an issue specific to the snap package. When I deleted the exising gitkraken configuration and installed it from a tarball, it worked without issue.

That means that in the future this script *should* solve the issue:

```bsh
rm -r ~/.gitkraken ~/.config/GitKraken
mkdir -p ~/apps/sources
cd ~/apps/sources
wget https://release.axocdn.com/linux/gitkraken-amd64.tar.gz
tar -xf gitkraken-amd64.tar.gz
mv gitkraken ~/apps
```

Then, add a desktop file that looks something like this (where `{{ user_home }}` is replaced by your home directory). Adding a desktop file enables you to get similar functionality to the snap package: GitKraken will be searchable by gnome.

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-SnapInstanceName=gitkraken
Name=GitKraken
Comment=Unleash your repo
GenericName=Git Client
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT={{ user_home }}/.local/share/applications/gitkraken_gitkraken.desktop {{ user_home }}/apps/gitkraken/gitkraken %U
Icon={{ user_home }}/apps/gitkraken/gitkraken.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Development;RevisionControl;
MimeType=text/plain;
StartupWMClass=gitkraken
```